# Typo3 tags need attention

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we really need tags named like [typo3-7.6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typo3-7.6.x) and [typo3-7.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typo3-7.x)? Yes the `.x` is part of the tag. These seem overly zealous with the `.x` part if that is to signify a patch-level. I find it very hard to read.

Comment: Some stats: There's only [12 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typo3-7.6.x%20not%20typo3%20not%20typoscript?mode=all) tagged with `typo3-7.6.x` that don't have the more general tag `typo3` or `typoscript`, and [5 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typo3-7.x%20not%20typo3%20not%20typoscript?mode=all) meeting the same criteria for `typo3-7.x`. [6 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typo3-7.x%20typo3-7.6.x?mode=all) have both `7.x` and `7.6.x` tags.

Comment: Why a tag for each version?! [tag:typo3] tag gets at most 70 questions in 30 days, ~2 questions day, this is the epitome of the balkanization of tags.